# MariaDB Galera cluster slow SST sync

Tags: rsync, cluster, mariadb, galera

I have a MariaDB Galera cluster with 3 nodes and I configured the SST transfer as

```
wsrep_sst_method = rsync
```

When I have to stop and restart a single node, the synchronization is very slow even if the node remained stopped only for 1 hour: it takes about 2 hours to sync.

Is there a way to speed up the synchronization time?

Thanks!

Comment: How big is `/var/lib/mysql/` folder? What is the speed between servers? Can you test the network speed?

Answer (score 0):

You could change SST method to `xtrabackup-v2`([here simple documentation](https://ospi.fi/blog/mariadb-galera-cluster-with-xtrabackup-v2-sst.html)) and configure MySQL as described in [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/08/20/optimizing-pxc-xtrabackup-state-snapshot-transfer/) in Percona blog. May be it could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! But according to http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/sst.html, rsync seems to be the fastest method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mat may be you right, but I'm talking about `xtrabackup-v2`, which could be faster then `xtrabackup` and `rsync`.